# Settlement of Shares Underlying a Covered Call Option

Tags: options, call-options, covered-call-writing, settling-and-clearing

If I buy 100 shares of XYZ stock one or two minutes before selling one XYZ call option, would this call option be considered "covered", or would it be considered "uncovered" until the 100 shares settle?

Comment: besides being a homework question or accounting/economics abstract, how does this relate to personal finance for you?

Answer (score 2):

It's a covered call.

When I want to create a covered call position, I don't need to wait before the stock transaction settles. I enter it as one trade, and they settle at different times.